# php replace consecutive same multiple digits with single digit

Tags: php, regex, replace

I want to replace same consecutive 4 or more same digits with single digit.
like 1111 => 1.
i tried with regex as

```
<?php
$str = "1111 2222 3333 4444 asdfasf 1111 2222 ";
echo preg_replace("/(^|(.)(?!\2))(\d)\3{3}(?!\3)/","<span class='background- 
color:yellow'>$1</span>",$str);
```

But same not replacing.
Please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output from your input there? You don't say anything about the `<span...` part, that's not a replacement with a single digit, that's an HTML string?

Comment: html here i added to highlight for test. i want multiple same digit will be replaced with the single digit itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the pattern

```
/(\d)\1{3,}/
```

to match a digit in a group, then repeat that same group 3 or more times, and then replace the whole matched substring with the matched digit character:

```
$1
```

Full code:

```
$str = "1111 2222 3333 4444 asdfasf 1111 2222 ";
echo preg_replace('/(\d)\1{3,}/', "$1", $str);
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 asdfasf 1 2
```

This will also match repeated numbers that are part of other numbers, like `122221` - if you don't want that, add a word boundary to to the beginning and end:

```
/\b(\d)\1{3,}\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regex `(\d)\1{3,}` and replace with `$1`

This will match the digit occurring four or more times consecutively

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/64p87q/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this (it's more efficient the way the other answers have it).  But I thought why not post something a bit different...

```
$str = "1111 2222 3333 4444 asdfasf 1111 2222 ";

$range = range(0,9);
$patterns = array_map(function($num){
    return '/'.$num.'{4,}/';
},$range);

echo preg_replace($patterns, $range, $str);
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 asdfasf 1 2
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/234dae910c84137466726fa8fcd60be22b783365)

The patterns this uses is basically,  `/x{4,}/` where `x` is a number `0` - `9`.  So this uses an array of patterns to replace with an array of replacements.  Which is why it's less efficient, but they beat me to the other answer....

Now that I think about it, it could also be done with `\1` like this

```
$str = "1111 2222 3333 4444 asdfasf 1111 2222 ";

$patterns = array_map(function($num){
    return '/('.$num.'){4,}/';
},range(0,9));

echo preg_replace($patterns, '\1', $str);
```

That way it uses only 1 array...

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a69327efa831175d0727a69996577730c21a064b)

The array of patterns looks like this

```
[
  0 => '/(0){4,}/',
  1 => '/(1){4,}/',
  2 => '/(2){4,}/',
  3 => '/(3){4,}/',
  4 => '/(4){4,}/',
  5 => '/(5){4,}/',
  6 => '/(6){4,}/',
  7 => '/(7){4,}/',
  8 => '/(8){4,}/',
  9 => '/(9){4,}/',
]
```

Cheers!